# Create CSS header with centered logo, and lines that extend out from the right/left of transparent PNG

Tags: html, css, web

I've been trying to create this look:

[image]

What I thought was a clever way of doing it was to create an unordered list, have the bars on the left/right use 100% of the width not taken by the logo.

Apparently, I've failed at this.

The site in question is live, and you can visit it here (to see the code I've created so far): http://amydemosphotography.smugmug.com/galleries

I've not been able to make the bars and the logo occupy the same vertical space, and I haven't been able to solve the issue of how to make them grow/shrink with the browser window while allowing the logo to 1) always stay cenetered, and 2) always have padding on the left/right (so the lines don't ever touch/go under it).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you willing to use javascript? What's your minimum resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
<h1><img src="http://cdn.smugmug.com/photos/2254208423_RS5b5Z6-O.png" alt="Logo"></h1>
```

--

```
body {
    padding-top: 3em;
}
h1 {
    color: #333;
    display: table;
}
h1:after,
h1:before {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent 40%, #87a 40%, #87a 60%, transparent 60%);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(transparent 40%, #87a 40%, #87a 60%, transparent 60%);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(transparent 40%, #87a 40%, #87a 60%, transparent 60%);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(transparent 40%, #87a 40%, #87a 60%, transparent 60%);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(transparent 40%, #87a 40%, #87a 60%, transparent 60%);
    content: '';
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
/* Everything below allows us to have a little bit of space between the title and the decoration */
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;
       -moz-background-clip: padding;
            background-clip: padding;
}
h1:after {
    border-left: 1.5em solid transparent;
}
h1:before {
    border-right: 1.5em solid transparent;
}
​
```

And here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/XjXYE/

Comment: The problem, really, is that there's a textured background I need to deal with.... That's what's causing me to have issues. :(

Comment: Will this work with the transparent logo and background texture? :)

Comment: ok, stupid question.. How would I move the lines UP without breaking the CSS3? Here's my edits: http://jsfiddle.net/XjXYE/14/

Comment: Sorry, glad you got it all sorted! You could also just use a background-image on the pseudo-elements, instead of a linear-gradient.